# Get shell name with go

Tags: shell, go, command-line-interface

I'm running an CLI app and I want to know the user's shell. I tried to use

```golang
exec.Command("echo", "$0")
```

but it logs `$0`. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the user's shell"?  Do you mean the shell that invoked the process (it may not have been started by a shell), or the user's preferred shell as set in the environment variable SHELL, or the path of a shell in the `struct passwd` for the user (as returned by getpwuid), or something else?

Comment: `$0` doesn't represent a shell, it's the fist argument in the command (which just happens to be the shell when you're executing _a shell_). Also, `exec.Command` does not execute a shell, unless you tell it to, in which case you know what shell that is because you passed it in. You could look for `$SHELL` in the environment on most unix systems.

Comment: More importantly, what do you plan to *do* with this information? Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I want to send metrics about which shell the users are using to run the cli app

Comment: This code __doesn't run a shell at all__. It only runs `/bin/echo`. So, you don't get any shell parameter expansions because *there is no shell*.

Comment: Moreover, there _doesn't exist_ a standardized way to request the same shell that the user who launched your program is running (which I assume is what you mean by "the user's shell"). You can run `exec.Command("sh", "-c", "echo \"$0\"")`, but that's running `sh`, not the user's shell.

Comment: The closest you can get is getting the command of [your process's parent PID](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getppid), which may or may not be the user's shell, and which may or may not even work depending on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want two things:

1. the UID of the current process
2. the configured shell of that UID

[os/user](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/) can give you the former but after quick searches for 'passwd' or 'pwent' or 'getpwent' (the appropriate libc call) I haven't found a go library that can get you the latter. `/etc/passwd` is trivial to parse and includes this information once you have the UID, however, so this is what I'd do.

Windows is obviously going to be different, but Darwin might also actually ignore this /etc file and require that you call libc to reach the truth.

It's also *conceiveable* that your program is always called with some other shell than the configured one, and if this is your concern you'll have to use something like [go-ps](https://github.com/mitchellh/go-ps/) and trace PPIDs until you find something that you believe to be a shell.